# Jquery datatables Serverside Processing with special characters (Ex:äää)

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using the datatables for my application, I have used server side pagination [JSP-Struts-2] , I went through different threads on the special character search issue .. still i am unable to figure it out . The regular English text search works fine .. Pls Let me know wot changes needs to be done inorder to make special character search .

Please find my code below ..

```
$(document).ready(function(){

                        oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
                            "bJQueryUI": true,
                            "bPaginate": true,
                           "bServerSide": true,
                            "sAjaxSource": "ajaxUserSearch.action",
                            "bProcessing": true,
                                     "bLengthChange": false,                               
                            "oLanguage": {
                            "sUrl": '<s:text name="datatables.msgs"/>'
                                },

                                    "aoColumnDefs": [
       {
           "aTargets":[0],

           "fnCreatedCell": function(nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol)
           {
               $(nTd).css('text-align', 'center');
           },
           "mData": null,
           "mRender": function( data, type, full) {    // You can use <img> as well if you want
           //console.log(full[7]);
           if(full[7]=='ACTIVE' || full[7]=='Active')
                            {
                                return '<input type="radio" name="salesOrgSelection" onclick="setUsrId('+full[9]+',2)"  /> <td>';
                            }
                            else{
                                return '<input type="radio" name="salesOrgSelection" onclick="setUsrId('+full[9]+',1)"  /> <td>';
                            }

           },

            }

    ]
                        });
                                oTable.fnSetColumnVis( 9, false );

                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

IN THE SERVER_processing.php FIND:

```
mysql_select_db( $gaSql['db'], $gaSql['link'] ) or
    die( 'Could not select database '. $gaSql['db'] );
```

ADD AFTER

```
//To send utf8 data to MySql - needed if you need to inject utf8 data for search
    mysql_query("SET character_set_client=utf8", $gaSql['link']);
    mysql_query("SET character_set_connection=utf8", $gaSql['link']);

//To read utf8 data from MySql - needed if your result set contains utf8 data
    mysql_query("SET character_set_results=utf8", $gaSql['link']);
```